# How to program a vote up system?

Tags: php, mysql, counter, increment

I am in the very beginnings of teaching myself php.
I am giving myself micro projects to push myself.

Thus far I have a MYSQL database, created through a php form. One Column is for karma.
I have the values of the database table display in an html table, and at the end of each row, I would like a click on a hyperlink, lets say a plus sign, to increase that row's karma level by 1. Then the plus sign would go away.

I should that each row has an auto increment integer as a primary key.

Comment: Wheres the real question? Well, maybe you want AJAX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this example, let's assume you're voting on so-answers. This will require at least three tables:

**Users**, **Answers**, **Votes**

The votes table will hold all the history:

```
voteid | userid | answerid | value
----------------------------------
   1   |   12   |   383    |   1
   2   |   28   |   383    |  -1  (negative number would require signed values)
```

In this example, we see that two votes have been recorded. Users 12 and 28 both voted on Answer 383. User 12 loved it, and added 1 to its support. User 28 didn't like it, and subtracted 1 from its support.

Anytime a user votes, you should first check to see if that user has already voted on that particular question. If they have, you can reject any further attempts to vote, or overwrite their old vote with a new one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM votes 
WHERE (userid = 12) 
  AND (answerid = 383)
```

That's a very simple example query that will tell you if the user has already voted or not. If it returns records, you know they've voted. You can respond with a very nice "Sorry, you've already voted." message, or you can overwrite it:

```
UPDATE votes 
SET value = $votevalue 
WHERE (userid = 12) 
  AND (answerid = 383)
```

#### Having said that, let's look at how SO accomplishes this:

When you click the up-vote arrow, SO fires a request off to a url like the following:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1303528/vote/2
```

In this URL, we can see the vote is being cast on post #1303528. And the vote-type is represented by 2. This 2 likely represents "add one." You could use a more basic url, and go with something like:

```
    vote.php?answerid=383&vote=1
```

The vote.php page would have code similar to the following:

*(warning: do not use this code as-is. It is meant to be an example, not a solution)*

```
if ($_GET) {

  $userid   = $_SESSION["userid"]; // assumes the user is logged in via SESSIONS
  $answerid = $_GET["answerid"];
  $votetype = $_GET["vote"];

  $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM votes 
            WHERE (userid = {$userid}) 
              AND (answerid = {$answerid})";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    # User has voted
    print "Sorry, you are only allowed one vote.";
  } else {
    # User has not voted, cast the vote
    $query = "INSERT INTO votes (userid, answerid, votevalue)
              VALUES({$userid},{$answerid},{$vote})";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) {
      print "Your vote has been recorded.";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It might also be a good idea to cache vote counts, especially for popular questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Personally I like Jonathan's answer.**

However if you feel like you might need more info, I might be able to help.

As a small side project I tried to make a quote database like bash.org for my university.
It was developed using MySql and PHP, it has posting/voting much like what you are trying to accomplish. 
It is by no means a well designed web app. However it might be able to get you going in the right direction.

**Live testing site**: [link](http://lame.ws/rit/) (be gentle!)

**Code on GitHub**: [link](http://github.com/bgianfo/rit-qdb/tree/master)

I would take a look at the [database schema](http://github.com/bgianfo/rit-qdb/blob/d6ff624e17c01ace7d809ae0998b4597dfffb5db/db.sql) , the [php](http://github.com/bgianfo/rit-qdb/blob/d6ff624e17c01ace7d809ae0998b4597dfffb5db/vote.php)-[db-integration](http://github.com/bgianfo/rit-qdb/blob/d6ff624e17c01ace7d809ae0998b4597dfffb5db/inc/config.php) and the [ajax to update a vote](http://github.com/bgianfo/rit-qdb/blob/d6ff624e17c01ace7d809ae0998b4597dfffb5db/inc/footer.inc#L59).

The code is fairly simple and straight foreword. One thing of note is the "**filter_input**"s, These functions are from a PHP library to sanitize user inputs to prevent SQL injections.